# Programmatically adding items from a list to a TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have an Android project I am working on.  I am fairly new to Android Development so I have some code in a MainActivity.java file that I am working on Creating a Table Layout for but the way my code currently is I can only add one item from that list what can I do in the Activity.java class to change this so it will programmatically add all of my Mcdonalds objects too the Table.  What can I do to add both rows to the view on MainActivity.java?

Activity_Main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".ShelterActivity" >

 <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:stretchColumns="0">

   <TableRow 
       android:id="@+id/TableRow01" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="Address"
         android:width="250px"
         android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="Distance"
         android:width="250px"
         android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/TextView03" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="ETA"
         android:width="250px"
         android:textStyle="bold"></TextView> 
   </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>  
 </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_shelter);
         List<McDonalds> mcdList = new ArrayList<McDonalds>();

               ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

                     // get a reference for the TableLayout
                     TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);

                     HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
               // create a new TableRow
                     TableRow row = new TableRow(this);


         //This will be replaced by a Read Only Stored procedure that gets the List of Shelters
         McDonalds mcdonalds = new McDonalds("720 N Main St, Roswell, NM", 1.08, 8.0);
         mcdList.add(mcdonalds);
         McDonalds mcdonalds1 = new McDonalds("1804 S Main St, Roswell, NM", 2.9, 12.0);
         mcdList.add(mcdonalds1);
         for (McDonalds mcD : mcdList){
              // create a new TextView
                    TextView t = new TextView(this);
                    TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
                    TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
        String mcdAddress = mcD.getAddress();
        String distance = mcD.getDistance().toString();
        String ETA = mcD.getETA().toString();
        t.setText(mcdAddress);
        t1.setText(distance);
        t2.setText(ETA);
        row.addView(t);
        row.addView(t1);
        row.addView(t2);


    }
    // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    ll.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}
```

As seen in the code above there should be two items in the list and I need a way to add both items with the `ll.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` but this will throw a error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close but What you have to do is:

1. Remove your TableRow from your xml.
2. Always create a new TableRow in a loop.
3. All your TextViews need a layout params set by `setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))`;
4. Add table row to a table layout also in a loop
5. I would say MATCH_PARENT would be better for each table row width

The other way to do it would be to make an xml file with  and it's textViews inside of it. Inflate the xml with LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(...), fill all 3 textviews finding them by id and add this inflated tableRow to a tableLayout

Comment: The table row in the xml is just for the Column Headers.

Comment: If it's column headers only - it's fine then. Let me know if everything is clear.

Comment: I know its late, but for anyone else having issues with this, here is a video that really helped me a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzVS5iyBm6I