# I want to arrange ArrayList values in ListView

Tags: android, arraylist, tablelayout

I am work on ArrayList.I want to display ArrayList in ListView ,I don't have any idea about using ArrayList in ListView.

[image]

In the picture "Cumputer Science" is the subject ,it should come under sub and other values also come under each one.

//layout

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/login"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="175dp" android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:textSize="16dp" android:text="Sub" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:textSize="16dp" android:text="Mon" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:textSize="16dp" android:text="Tue" android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:textSize="16dp" android:text="Wed" android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:textSize="16dp" android:text="Thu" android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"/>
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:textSize="16dp" android:text="Fri" android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

          </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

     <ListView android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/getAttdnce_lv">

    </ListView>

   </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try using grid layout. I think it is more suitable for your design. And check with `column span` attribute.

Comment: y u don't apply the css in you layout?

Comment: post ur layout what u have tried

Comment: I just want to arrange these values .I no need to use css

Comment: @ShahidBangash post your xml file.

Comment: Please watch The World of ListView. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&ei=lqt1U6LYBJDdoATa74GgBA&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=085gPMuo_gf8ksicjRpLQA

Answer (score 1):

Try to use TableLayout and then create rows dynamically according to your need.

Comment: I have to call arraylist in a row, arraylist will return multiple values,these values will diplay in a single cell which is a problem for me.I don't want to display these values in a single cell ,I want to display  these values in a specific cell.

Comment: @ShahidBangash you can create as many cells as you want. Add the <TableRow /> tags equal to size of your arraylist and add the children of the <TableRow>. Each child will be considered as a column. Do this all in your code, just define <TableLayout> in xml. Here's a [good example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/) for basics

Comment: what do u mean by tags ?

Comment: @ShahidBangash TableLayout is an xml tag you can use in your layout files. Now in code, loop through your arraylist and for each item, create an TableRow by new TableRow(this). Now for each value you want to add as column, call tablerow.addView(new TextView(this).setText("Test")) and finally call tableLayout.addView(tableRow). Is it clear now?

Comment: Brother that is something else,It is easy to make columns in row but i call arraylist.If you have a code plz share with me.

Comment: I think this is the best way for you to show the samething you want. I do not have any code at this time but I can explain it in more detail if you want. I am sure this is the right, easy and proper way to do it. Also some other links that can help you are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279501/programatically-adding-tablerow-to-tablelayout-not-working)
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485044/programmitically-adding-items-from-a-list-to-a-tablelayout)
The second one has same requirements as yours.

Comment: ArrayList<Double> debtList = datasource.debtList;(Can you explain this point.What is datasource)
ArrayList<Double> feeList = datasource.feeList;
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
for(int i=0;i<debtList.size();i++)
{
    TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
    double debt = debtList.get(i);
    double fee = feeList.get(i);
    TextView tvDebt=new TextView(this);
    tvDebt.setText(""+debt);
    TextView tvFee=new TextView(this);
    tvFee.setText(""+fee);
    row.addView(tvDebt);
    row.addView(tvFee);
    table.addView(row);
}

Comment: what is "datasource".I am confuse in datasource.debtList. I know debtList is an arraylist but what is datasource.

Comment: That is not usefult to you simply use the arraylist object. If you have some variable ArrayList<Double> feeList. Just use that directly. You don't need first two lines where datasource is used. Remove that and all will be working fine and if that helps don't forget to mark this as answer.

Comment: column width is not set.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public static final String[] Subject = new String[] { "Maths","Computer", "english"};
    private ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Subject);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```